# pip install -e doesn't allow to import via package dir

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

*Easy script to reproduce bug in the end of the question*

*This was also submitted as a bug on [pip's github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10810)*

For a pkg structured like this:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── my_pkg
        ├── __init__.py
        └── main.py
```

and a setup.py like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='test-pkg',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={
        'my_pkg': 'src/my_pkg',
    },
)
```

**creating a wheel and installing it allows me to import "my_pkg", but installing the package using `pip install -e .` doesn't. Why?**

Installing via wheel allows for importing "my_pkg" while installing via "-e" only allows for importing the "src" which defeats the purpose, as "src" is not the package dir

```sh
python -c "import my_pkg"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'
```

pip version: 21.3.1 (latest)

---

To summarize:

Working:

1. `pip install .`
2. `python setup.py bdist_wheel && pip install dist/*whl`

Not working:

1. `pip install -e .`
2. `python setup.py develop` (which is what `pip install -e` runs, but I wanted to make sure nothing got lost in the transition)
3. `pip install -e .` and then editing the /lib/python3.6/site-packages/test-pkg.egg-link and adding "src" to the path

---

Oopsie...

From [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/python_eggs.html):

*For the .egg-info format, however, **the base location is the directory that contains the .egg-info**, and thus it is the directory that must be added to sys.path to make the egg importable. (Note that this means that the “normal” installation of a package to a sys.path directory is sufficient to make it an “egg” if it has an .egg-info file or directory installed alongside of it.)*

I'm not entirely sure this means I'm screwed, but it might. Is there any way to go around this?

---

Bug reproduce script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mkdir -p reproduce_pip_install_e_bug/src/my_pkg
cd reproduce_pip_install_e_bug
touch src/my_pkg/__init__.py

echo "
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='test-pkg',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={
        'my_pkg': 'src/my_pkg',
    },
)
" > setup.py

virtualenv -p python3.6 good_venv > /dev/null && . good_venv/bin/activate && pip install . -vvv &> .good_installation.log && python -c "import my_pkg"
echo this was successful, however, next command will break
virtualenv -p python3.6 bad_venv > /dev/null && . bad_venv/bin/activate && pip install -e . -vvv &> .bad_installation.log && python -c "import my_pkg"
```

Comment: Where are you sitting when you `pip install -e .`? I believe it needs to be in the directory with `setup.py`. What error are you getting if that's where you are?

Comment: from the main dir, i.e. near `setup.py`

Comment: I was able to `pip install -e .` with the folder structure and `setup.py` shown in your code no problem. What error are you getting?

Comment: updated my question to show the error

Comment: From which directory are you running `python -c "import my_pkg"`?

Comment: From same dir I installed, but since I'm in a virtualenv, I should be able to do it from anywhere

Comment: In contrast to Engineero, I can confirm this problem: `my_pkg`, or `test_pkg`, is not importable. Further, `test-pkg.egg-link` in `lib/python3.x/site-packages/` points to the base directory, which is not where `my_pkg` can be found or imported, since there is still a `src/` directory in between. This may be a shortcoming/oversight of `pip install -e`.

Comment: @9769953 - yes, this is exactly what I see. Thanks. I didn't get how Engineero managed to do what was claimed. About shortcoming/oversight - I'm not sure. What do you think of the quote from setuptools docs I added?

Comment: I don't know. I tried moving the whole egg-info directory into src/ (and adjusting the egg-link file to include src/), but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @9769953 - same. Tried duplicating it, editing the egg-link and a few other weird stuff, nothing works. I also can't find any meaningful doc about egg-link and how they should work

Comment: Never mind.....

Comment: I would recommend trying with: `package_dir={'': 'src'}` in your `setup.py`. Editable installations and `package_dir` modifications do not work well together.

Comment: This is poorly documented, but you can see it here: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#using-find-or-find-packages and here (albeit with `setup.cfg`): https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#using-a-src-layout

Comment: @sinoroc I already use package dir. Do you suggest using it with an empty string as a key? Didn't see this should affect anything...

Comment: @CIsForCookies Yes, try with an empty string as I wrote in the comment. This way has always worked, for me at least. And this is how I have seen it done in many other projects. If it does not work, maybe there are some other remnants of previous installations and/or builds that need to be cleaned up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**== Workaround ==**

`PYTHONPATH` to the rescue!!!

running `export PYTHONPATH=<abspath_to_src>` circumvents the issue. However, `sys.path` in this case is not similar to the `sys.path` of `pip install .` - they both have the path of src but the `pip install -e .` would also have the path of the root directory - allowing to import it, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: From my experience and from reading things here and there, I came to the conclusion that manually modifying `PYTHONPATH` and/or `sys.path` is almost never the solution. I would recommend against it. -- But as always: if it works for you, that is what matters.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a so-called *`src`-layout* with *setuptools* the setup.py should look like this :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='test-pkg',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={
        '': 'src',
    },
)
```

The `package_dir` should get an empty string as key.

It is kind of explained in the "*deprecated*" documentation of *setuptools*:

> The keys to this dictionary are package names, and an empty package name stands for the root package. The values are directory names relative to your distribution root. In this case, when you say `packages = ['foo']`, you are promising that the file `lib/foo/__init__.py` exists.

-- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/distutils/setupscript.html?highlight=package_dir#listing-whole-packages

...and kind of in the newest version of the documentation, but it is somewhat possible to piece things together:

- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#using-find-or-find-packages
- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#using-a-src-layout

Comment: Will try soon enough. I added a comment in the GitHub page which I won't copy here as it becomes tiresome messaging on 2 platforms ;). Anyways, thanks!!